# javascript: firefox selectedIndex on combobox

Tags: javascript, firefox, combobox

I have a simple little combobox on my web page:

```
<select id="famNum" onchange="familySize()">
       <option value="0">0</option>
       <option value="1">1</option> <!-- etc -->
</select>
```

And if I use:

```
famNum.selectedIndex = 0;
```

it works fine in Safari but not in firefox.  I even tried using jQuery:

```
$('#famNum').selectedIndex = 0;
```

but still firefox won't do it.  How can I get this to work in firefox?  It keeps saying "famNum is not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only some browsers add all the elements that have an id to the window object. This is non-standard behaviour, and Firefox for example doesn't do that. To access the element you should use the `getElementById` method:

```
document.getElementById('famNum').selectedIndex = 0;
```

If you want to use jQuery, the call doesn't return an element, it returns a jQuery object. You can either use a jQuery method to set the attribute:

```
$('#famNum').attr('selectedIndex', 0);
```

or you can get the element out of the jQuery object:

```
$('#famNum')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: It should be getElementById not GetElementById.
It wont let me edit only 1 letter so just letting everyone know in case they face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer startet to expose elements with ids or names as global objects. Safari seems to have adopted that behaviour. Use `getElementById()` to get it working on every browser.

```
document.getElementById("famNum").selectedIndex = 0;
```